# virtio-scsi storage controller on Ubuntu 22.04 guest in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, drivers, virtualbox, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 guest, including Guest Additions, on Windows 11 host on VirtualBox. My network speed in Ubuntu is terrible. On Windows I get 900 Mbps. On Ubuntu I get only 50 Mbps. I basically tried everything I could find.

I have an Intel i9 and with 128 GB RAM Lenovo. I setup VirtualBox as follows:

System->Processor: 12 CPU with Enable PAE/NX checked.

System->Acceleration: Paravirtualization Interface: Hyper-V with Nested Paging enabled.

Display ->Screen: Video Memory: 256 MB, Graphics Controller, VMSVGA and 3D Acceleration unchecked.

Storage->Controller: IDE Type: USB (Host I/O Cache checked); Optical Drive USB Port 0, Live CD/DVD unchecked.

Storage->Controller: SATA Type: AHCI (Port Count = 1, Host I/O Cache unchecked); Ubuntu_22.04.vdi: Hard Disk SATA Port 0, SSD and Hot-pluggable unchecked.

Network->Adapter 1: Bridged Adapter (Intel Ethernet (17) I219-LM; Adapter Type: Intel Pro/1000 MT Desktop, Promiscuous Mode: Deny, and Cable Connected checked.

I read that setting the Network Adapter to Paravirtualized Network (virtuo-net) could improve connection performance. However, when I set that up Ubuntu could not connect to the Internet.

I also read that setting the storage controller types to virtio-scsi could improve performance. When I did that Ubuntu did not boot, perhaps because it didn't recognize the controller.

On a side note, copy/paste between host and guest is not working although Shared Clipboard and Drag'n'Drop are both set to Bidirectional.

Any help is greatly appreciated as I'm new to VirtualBox and Ubuntu.